# When converting to parametric equation, should plus-minus sign be used?

Tags: radicals, parametric

I'm following a tutorial which says this:

Convert the following equation to a pair of parametric equations for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $t$:
$$y=x^2+3$$
Step 1 - Set $t$ equal to $x^2$:
$$t=x^2$$
Step 2 - Solve for x:
$$x=\sqrt t$$
Step 3 - Substitute $t$ for $x^2$ in $y=x^2+3$:
$$y=t+3$$

In step 2, I was thinking it should actually be $x=\pm\sqrt t$ instead of $x=\sqrt t$. Is that correct, if the domain of $y=x^2+3$ is all real numbers?

Comment: depends upon the domain of the function.

Comment: @RamanujanXV I made the question more specific. Domain is all real numbers.

Comment: It seems to me that $x = \pm \sqrt t$ is not parameterizing $x$ in terms of $t$. A parameterization should take one value of $t$ and produce one value each of $x$ and $y$. You can get this (trivially) from $x = t$, which may seem silly, but this curve is already essentially parameterized. It's a silly exercise. What tutorial is this? Maybe there are better ones.

Comment: @DavidK This tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97pe-QlSGqA) at 31:55

Comment: Seeing this in context now, it's only one of many ways that the tutorial parameterizes pieces of parabolas. Notice how you are invited to pause the video and try $x=\sqrt t$ for $-2\leq t\leq 2$ before continuing. I think you're supposed to discover that it doesn't work, because you can't take the square root of negative numbers. And then when we change it to $t\geq 0$ we get just part of the right-hand side of the parabola, because that's how this parameterization works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it is explicitly claimed that $x \geq 0$ or $x < 0$ (exclusive), there is no much you can do other than considering each case separately.

Otherwise, as previously mentioned in the comments, it is more interesting to consider the parametrization $x = t$ and $y = t^{2} + 3$.

Hopefully this helps !